# automorphism groups of hyerelliptic curves in positive charactersitic

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-curves

It appears that the automorphism groups of hyperelliptic curves are at least well studied, if not understood, in the characteristic zero case. I would imagine that most of these results would carry to the case of a hyperelliptic curve over an algebraically closed field $k$, of characteristic $p>0$, as long as $p$ does not divide the order of the automorphism group.

I wondered if anyone would have any references for papers considering the positive characteristic case where the characteristic ${\bf can}$ divide the order of the automorphism group, and the field is not finite.